# Spherical Camera

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

See my edit below.

I have a sphere being drawn at the origin. My camera is looking at the sphere at a radius of 3 units. I am trying to make the camera orbit the sphere using a 2D joystick. I'm currently using the code below to orbit the sphere but I'm not sure how to allow the joystick to control the rotation in the direction that joystick is pointing. My joystick provides angles of 0 degrees being up and as you go counter-clockwise the degrees go up to 360. The further away the joystick is from it's central starting point, the rotation speed will increase. Im just not sure how to go about doing that.

```
PIOVER180 = Math.PI/180;
rho = 3;
theta = (theta+1)%360;
phi = (theta+1)%360;

camera.position.x = (float) (rho * Math.sin(theta * PIOVER180) * Math.cos(phi * PIOVER180));
camera.position.y = (float) (rho * Math.cos(theta * PIOVER180));
camera.position.z = (float) (rho * Math.sin(theta * PIOVER180) * Math.sin(phi * PIOVER180));
camera.normalizeUp();
```

libGDX provides a nice `PerspectiveCamera` class, and I was hoping to extend it for a `SphericalCamera` and use that to call my rotations when I need them.

**Edit:**

I think if I can just figure out how to make a 2D joystick manipulate the `theta` and `phi` variables correctly then it should work fine. `theta` is the angle between the positive x axis and the point on the sphere, `phi` where on the z axis the the point lies (positive or negative), and `rho` is the distance from the center point (0, 0, 0) to the point on the sphere (basically the radius)

Comment: It's usually better to use `glRotate(sensitivity,joystickMovementY,joystickMovementX,0.0f)` on the scene rather than moving the camera

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I am going to have a bunch of models orbiting my sphere with bullets as well. I figured it would just be easier to just change the view of the camera?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with moving the camera as such. It's just that you'll end up implementing a bunch of maths methods that do exactly what `glRotate()`, `glTranslate()` etc already do.

Comment: Yea I think I am noticing exactly what you mean haha... I hope once I get it set up though that it will be pretty easy. I've actually decided to go the route of using quaternions for rotation, trying to wrap my head around them at the moment.

Comment: Check out http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html and http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Using_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation for quaternions. The second link has code samples as well

Comment: Nice thanks! Those links are super helpful. Especially the second where it has an example of how to apply it to a camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to rotate around a sphere in a manner controlled by the joystick while looking at the center, right?

Well if the joystick gives you an angle "ang" in degrees, with 0 being up, then the components for each axis would be:

```
double x = Math.sin(ang*Math.PI/180.);
double y = Math.cos(ang*Math.PI/180.);
```

What you could then do is translate your camera on its own UP/LEFT plane by these amounts, possibly using a "speed" parameter:

```
Vector3 left = new Vector3(camera.up).crs(camera.direction).scl((float)(speed*x));
Vector3 up = new Vector3(camera.up).scl((float)(speed*y));
camera.position.add(left).add(up);
```

At which point your camera will leave the desired orbit so you need to bring it back:

```
camera.position.nor().scl(rho);
```

In your code sample you do not update the direction of the camera after changing the position but it is necessary according to your description. To look at the origin:

```
camera.direction.set(camera.position).scl(-1).nor();
```

And finally update the up vector and the model matrix:

```
camera.normalizeUp();
camera.update(false);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have since switched from libGDX to Unity3D, but the theory is practically the same (after looking at my Unity3D code, I have a very similar process as to what you posted minus a slightly different API)... I'll mark this as the accepted answer because it is correct, and will work for libGDX. Appreciate it.

Comment: If I comment `camera.direction.set(camera.position).scl(-1).nor();` line, this func allows me to move camera. How to change your function that it works with offset? The problem is it resets offset  and sphere in the centre everytime.

Comment: Is there a way to use this code for an object orbiting the sphere, instead of the camera, with the camera in a fixed position?